# SharePoint webpart & workflow time is different

Tags: workflow

I have a record that is created through a custom webpart and updated through multiple workflows (Triggered on new item and also item update)

The time that the record is created is totally different from the time when record is updated through the SharePoint workflow. It is a difference of 8 hours.

Do note that the first workflow runs almost instantaneously however the time still widely varies (8 hours).

I tried restarting the SP Timer, SP Administration services and also tried restarting the server but to no avail.

The Central Admin web app timezone is the same as the one in the server at the moment, i.e. UTC +8.

Is there anywhere else where I should change my date/time settings, that I had missed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the regional time settings in site.

Comment: @AmalHashim where do I check those? Thanks.

Comment: Under site settings

Comment: May i know which option i should choose to view the settings under Site Settings? Thx

Comment: Check Site Settings > Regional Settings (Under 'Site Administration')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by both commentators on the question,

Site Settings -> Regional Settings (Under 'Site Administration') is the answer.

Hence in conclusion, there are 2 places to change in SharePoint when changing date/time.

1. Central Administration

   - Application Management
   - General Settings
   - Default Time Zone
2. Site Settings

   - Regional Settings (Under 'Site Administration')